# If two direct sums of modules are isomorphic, when do we know that the components are isomorphic?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, direct-sum, valuation-theory

I have a commutative unital ring $A$ and $A$-modules $M_1,\ldots,M_n$, $N_1,\ldots,N_n$ with $$M_1\oplus\cdots\oplus M_n\cong N_1\oplus\cdots\oplus N_n.$$ Are there any particular conditions on $A$ and/or the modules in question under which we know that there exists a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ for which $M_i\cong N_{\sigma(i)}$ for all $i$?

The specific example that motivated this question concerns the case where $A$ is a discrete valuation ring with irreducible element $p\in A$ and $$A/p^{k_1}A\oplus\cdots\oplus A/p^{k_n}A\cong A/p^{m_1}A\oplus\cdots\oplus A/p^{m_n}A.$$

Comment: Can you do the special case of vector spaces?  Or the special case of Abelian groups?

Comment: For your concrete case, you could use the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over pid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain). For the generalized question, we can expect the answer will be not always since for $M=\oplus_{1}^{\infty}R$ and $N=R$, we have $M\oplus M\cong N\oplus M$.

Comment: @user85667 Thanks, got it now. I didn't realise that the decomposition from the structure theorem was unique

Comment: A general principle would be if $\mathrm{Hom}(M_i,N_j)=0$ for all $j\neq i$ (after appropriate permutation of the indices).